# Have or has in this sentence when talking about "one or the other"

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

Which of these two sentences is correct english?

> If you or a loved one has suffered from an injury

or:

> If you or a loved one have suffered from an injury

Considering that it is regarding "you ***or*** a loved one".

Answer (score 1):

‘Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage’ quotes with approval John B Bremner’s ‘Words on Words’:

> When “either” and “or” join subjects of different persons, make the
>   verb agree with the nearer subject.

This argues in favour of the first, but it is hardly more satisfactory than the second. Both might be found, but if you really don’t like either, then the only answer is to recast the sentence as something like:

> If a loved one has suffered from an injury, or even if you have
>   yourself . . .